# cheapest mode of transportation between Ghent and Paris

Tags: public-transport, europe, france, belgium, routes

What is the cheapest mode of transportation if one wishes to go from Ghent to Paris?

Comment: Cheapest and shortest are often mutually exclusive. High speed rail is quite fast, but usually more costly. A quick [Rome2Rio search](https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Ghent/Paris) will give you some options to compare, but the best choice will depend on your budget, priorities, and schedule.

Comment: @anomuse the original question asked about cheapest **and** shortest, it has been edited since then (after having been out on hold). You can vote to reopen by clicking on the “reopen” link.

Comment: Cheapest and shortest are not mutually exclusive. Cheapest and fastest can be.

Comment: Well, if the question is clear now, it should be put off hold. If still unclear, 
 suggestions to improve are most welcome. The answer by @anomuse has answered my query. That was what I wished to know

Comment: The shortest route given by Google maps is a 285-kilometer walking route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flixbus has [buses from Ghent to Paris](https://shop.flixbus.fr/search?atb_pdid=54dc5cf7-c647-4b87-8d8f-723e02d8b7ca&departureCity=2738&arrivalCity=2015&route=Ghent-Paris&rideDate=21.12.2018&adult=1&_locale=fr&wt_eid=2154483216082251486&wt_t=1544832218992&affiliate=%28not%20set%29%2C) from €13 exc VAT depending on the time of day (and day of week) you book.